# Console scripts outside the main module aren't packaged along (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

Behold, my tree:

```
src/
├── bin
│   ├── cli.py
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── api.py
│   ├── models
│   └── utils.py
```

Now, observe, my **setup.cfg**:

```ini
[options]
zip_safe = False
packages = find:
package_dir =
    =src

[options.package_data]
src/bin = *

[options.packages.find]
where =
    src

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    mycommand = bin.cli:main
```

That seemed fairly reasonable to me. Yet when I install this package in a new virtual environment (`pip install /path/to/package`), and I run `mycommand`, I get a very unreasonable answer: **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bin'**.

**NOTE** this *does* work if I do an editable install!

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe because `bin` is not a Python package and can not be imported, since it does not contain any `__init__.py` file. Also, build a `sdist` and/or `wheel` and check that `bin/cli.py` is in there.

Comment: it's not. I found that by including it inside the package I can get it to work, I just don't feel it is supposed to be there.

Comment: Your comment mentions `it` many times, but I have no idea what `it` refers to...